# How Can I Pass a Menu Function Int Value Back To Main To Access Other Menu Functions Using Switch Statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement, return-value, menuitem

I'm doing this for part of a school project and I am so lost and this is only the beginning of it. Our professor wants us to have 4 menu functions. Each menu has options to access other functions within the program. First, we are asked to have the program state if we would like to start or quit. That's no problem. My problem is when I run the main menu function and select an option I cannot get my choice to return to main to run the switch case to access the other menus. Right now I have all the other menus saying "coming soon..." just so I know I am getting it right. I'll add more once I get past this part. This is my first post here so I apologize if this is a lot of code to post. I greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    //declare all working variables: mOption, FManOption, COption...etc...
    int MOption = 0;
    int FManOption = 0;
    int FOption = 0;
    int COption = 0;
    int userChoice = 0;


    int n = mainMenu();

        switch(n)
        {
            case 1: while(FManOption != 3)
                    {
                        FManOption = FishermanMenu();
                        switch(FManOption)
                        {
                            case 1: //get a fisherman
                                    //count fisherman
                                    break;
                            case 2: //prompt for a ssn, validate, search
                                    //if found display everything about this fisherman
                                    break;
                            case 3: //hit any key to go back to main menu
                                    //reset FManOption
                                    break;
                            default: "error!";
                        }//end switch(FManOption)
                    }//end while(FManOption != 3)
                    break;
            default: printf("error");
        }

    return 0;
}
int mainMenu()
{
  int option = 0;

    printf("-------Welcome to the Fishing Tournament Main Menu!-------\n\n");
    do
    {
        printf("1 - Fisherman menu\n");
        printf("2 - Fish menu\n");
        printf("3 - Tournament(Catch) menu\n");
        printf("4 - Close Tournament (determine winner)\n");
        printf("5 - Quit Program\n\n");
        printf("Please select a menu option: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &option) != 1) /* check scanf() return value for input errors */
        {
          /* handle input error */
          return -1;
        }
    } while (option < 1 || option > 5); /* check the range of option ( 1 - 5) */

    return option; /* finally return the final correct option */
}

int FishermanMenu()
{
    printf("Coming soon...");
    /*
    -1-Register fisherman

    -2-Search fisherman

    -3-Go back to main menu
    */
    //FManOption
}//end Fisherman Menu
```

Comment: Please a create a [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's really hard to make something out of the code you have posted.

Comment: Sorry about that. I took out the extra menus to make it appear a little cleaner. It probably won't run correctly but that's fine as long as I can understand the concept.

Comment: Do I have to use `fgets()` ? I only ask because I am not comfortable using it yet and it wasn't mention in our assignment. So the way I am returning the variable back to main is correct though? I have it saying return 0; but I didn't think that was correct.

Comment: Again if you could at least make it compile, it would be much easier to help. `scanf()` is probably ok here.

Comment: The way your function is written, it will always return 0, furthermore, you ignore the return value of your function.

Comment: I got it to where it should compile now. Can you explain that for me please when you say it ignores the return value of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mainMenu()` function doesn't return anything other than **0**, in addition you ignore the return value in main, when you call `mainMenu();` (this shouldn't even compile btw), this is probably what you are looking for,

```
int mainMenu(void)
{
  int option = 0;

    printf("-------Welcome to the Fishing Tournament Main Menu!-------\n\n");
    do 
    {
        printf("1 - Fisherman menu\n");
        printf("2 - Fish menu\n");
        printf("3 - Tournament(Catch) menu\n");
        printf("4 - Close Tournament (determine winner)\n");
        printf("5 - Quit Program\n\n");
        printf("Please select a menu option: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &option) != 1) /* check scanf() return value for input errors */
        {
          /* handle input error */
          return -1;
        }
    } while (option < 1 || option > 5); /* check the range of option ( 1 - 5) */

    return option; /* finally return the final correct option */
}

int main(void)
{

  int n = mainMenu(); /* save the result to n */

  /* your code */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well that's a lot better but now I am getting an infinite loop saying "coming soon" a million times. I'll update what I have now.

Comment: @tlbiro It happens for the same reason, you never update the value of `FmanOptions`, you also need to call the function outside the while loop, in case it returns 3 in the first try.

Comment: You mean call it outside of the loop like this?
`case 1: FishermanMenu();
                    while(FManOption != 3)`

Comment: @tlbiro Yes but you need to save the result into a variable, the function returns something if you dont save it, you can't keep track, `FManOption = FishermanMenu();` is the way to go.

Comment: Wow. I swear I just did that but apparently I didn't. You have helped me more than anyone else and I greatly appreciate your time. Thank you so much! I'll try and muscle the rest out myself.